# Graph API - send mail with email id of any other tenant from my tenant's AAD app with app-only authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to send mail using graph api with email id (me@xyzabcd.com) where xyzabcd.com is my domain name. I have registered an azure active directory app with account type [Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts] and send email graph api permission for Application only. I have implemented the code from here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript-app-only?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3

Now, I want to send mail from other organization mail like joel@zetaweb.in. But this user exists in other tenant's organization. How do I get permission to send mail from this email id in my AAD app credentials (AppId, TenantId, clienSecret, etc) ?
I am asking this because account type is Multitenant, so i am assuming. There must be some way to achieve this. Please help

I tried to understand the multi tenant from this docs but its not clear how we do that. This is the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/multi-tenant-user-management-introduction

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I want to send mail from other organization mail like joel@zetaweb.in. But this user exists in other tenant's organization.

The first step would be that your application would need to be consented to in the other tenant, a step before that depending on the age of the app is publisher verification https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/publisher-verification-and-app-consent-policies-are-now/ba-p/1257374?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003178

> and send email graph api permission for Application only.

Application perissions by default give you rights to send from any mailbox in the tenant, the other tenant (depending on your relationship with it) may not want this so your application should be scoped down to just having access to the mailbox in question eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

The last step is that in your authentication code you need to make sure that

```
_settings.tenantId
```

is the tenantId of the target tenant.